# Why does Unix command `ping` fail yet I can access the URL via all internet browsers?

Tags: unix, ping

Currently I am accessing the Internet in a public library. Before using this access, one must accept the terms of use. After accepting these terms, my browser accesses any URL, e.g. cnn.com

In Unix, I enter the command `ping URL`, e.g. `ping cnn.com`, this command fails.

```
$  ping cnn.com
PING cnn.com (157.166.226.26): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
```

After ending this with `Control + C`, the output is

```
7 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Why exactly is `ping` not working in this case? How can I use this command successfully?

Comment: cnn.com doesn't answer to ping requests even through a full Internet access anyway. Try with www.google.com which is more icmp friendly.

Comment: @jiliagre `ping google.com` doesn't work either. I believe Jean-Baptiste Yunes is correct below. The library filters ICMP requests, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of network protocol. Ping uses ICMP and your browser HTTP to talk on the netork. It is highly like the network environment of your library filters network connexions by protocols for security reasons.

Comment: Based on what I've been trying, I suspect you're correct.